# Grep inside while loop removes the file!! [Bash script]

Tags: bash, grep

I'm working writing a bash script and I am becoming crazy with a mysterious loop.

I need to seek for a concrete code inside a text file (codigos.txt) that contains many codes and, if the code is found, I need to seek for the next one (siguienteCodigo++) until the code is not found, so I've written the next while loop (where $siguienteCodigo is the variable containing the code to search and $rutaOrigen is the path to the file containing the codes, codigos.txt):

```
while grep -F "$siguienteCodigo" "$rutaOrigen/codigos.txt"; do
    let siguienteCodigo++
done
```

But when I execute the script, my surprise is that it seems to find the codes but the codigos.txt file is removed!

Below is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
################################################################################
# SCRIPT PARA CODIFICAR RECURSIVAMENTE TODAS LAS FOTOGRAFÍAS DE LOS ARTÍCULOS  #
# Y REGISTRARLAS EN UNA HOJA DE CÁLCULO DE MICROSOFT EXCEL                     #
################################################################################
#
# Extraemos el día, mes, año, hora, minuto y segundo
day="$(date +%d)"
month="$(date +%m)"
year="$(date +%Y)"
hour="$(date +%H)"
minute="$(date +%M)"
second="$(date +%S)"
# Extraemos la ruta de origen, donde se ejecuta el script
rutaOrigen="$(pwd)"
# Recorremos todos los directorios listados recursivamente, a partir de la ruta
# de origen
for d in $(ls -R | grep "^\." | sed 's/://'); do
    # Cambiamos al directorio
    cd "$d"
    # Buscamos cuál es el último artículo codificado
    ultimoCodigo=$(printf "%08d" "0")
    # Recorremos todos los archivos que nos interesa listar, que son todos
    # los archivos con extensión .jpg .JPG y .txt
    for i in $(ls *.jpg *.JPG *.txt); do
        # Extraemos el nombre del archivo, sin extensión
        case "${i##*.}" in
            "jpg")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".jpg" "$i")";;
            "JPG")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".JPG" "$i")";;
            "txt")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".txt" "$i")";;
        esac
        # Extraemos los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo, que
        # corresponderán al "código 8" del artículo
        codigo8=$(expr substr "$fotoActual" 1 8)
        # Si los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo forman un numérico
        # entero y éste es mayor que el último "codigo 8" guardado,
        # inicialmente iniciado a 0...
        if [[ $codigo8 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( codigo8 > ultimoCodigo )); then
            # Guardamos el "código 8" actual como el último código,
            # es decir, como el último artículo codificado
            ultimoCodigo=$(printf "%08d" "$codigo8")
        fi
    done
    # Volvemos a recorrer todos los archivos que nos interesa listar, esta
    # vez para codificar los que no están codificados, es decir, los que
    # siguen al último artículo codificado
    for i in $(ls *.jpg *.JPG *.txt); do
        # Extraemos el nombre del archivo, sin extensión
        case "${i##*.}" in
            "jpg")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".jpg" "$i")";;
            "JPG")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".JPG" "$i")";;
            "txt")
                fotoActual="$(basename -s ".txt" "$i")";;
        esac
        # Extraemos los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo, que
        # corresponderán al "código 8" del artículo
        codigo8=$(expr substr "$fotoActual" 1 8)
        siguienteCodigo=$(($ultimoCodigo + 1))
        # Si los 8 primeros carácteres del archivo forman un numérico
        # entero y éste es mayor que el último "código 8" guardado...
        if [[ $codigo8 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( codigo8 <= ultimoCodigo )); then
            :
        else
            while grep -F "$siguienteCodigo" "$rutaOrigen/codigos.txt"; do
                let siguienteCodigo++
            done
            rutaActual="$(pwd)"
            carpetaActual="$(basename "$rutaActual")"
            caracteresCarpeta=$(expr length "$carpetaActual")
            descripcion="$(expr substr "$carpetaActual" 10 $caracteresCarpeta)"
            rutaActual="$(echo -e "$rutaActual" | sed 's/\//\\/g' | sed 's/\\media\\sf_E_DRIVE/E:/')"
            let ultimoCodigo++
            newFile=$(printf "%08d_${day}-${month}-${year}_${hour}-${minute}-${second}.jpg" "$siguienteCodigo")
            mv -- "$i" "$newFile"
            echo -e "$siguienteCodigo\t$rutaActual\t$descripcion\t$day/$month/$year\t$hour:$minute:$second" | awk -F '\t' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' OFS='\t' >> "$rutaOrigen/registroarticulos.xls"
        fi
    done
    cd "$rutaOrigen"
done
echo "Se creó una hoja de registro en $rutaOrigen/registroarticulos.xls"
echo "Todas las fotografías fueron codificadas correctamente :)"
exit 0
```

Comment: The issue will be difficult to reproduce by anyone but you. Nothing in the code suggests that a file could be removed. What you could try is to remove the loop from your script, re-run the script and check if the file still gets removed.

Comment: You execute a `mv` in your script while iterating over various files including *.txt. Could it be that you are accidentally moving/renaming codigos.txt? You can call `mv` with `-v` to produce some debugging output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is working on `.JPG`, `.jpg` and `.txt` files.

The `codigos.txt` file is renamed in the first run on the `.` directory derived from the `$(ls -R | grep "^\." | sed 's/://')` output.

In a testrun on my machine the file `codigos.txt` was renamed to `00000002_02-10-2015_13-18-59.jpg`